# pass the data from table to popwindow in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I m new to angular. I have table which contains data of 100+ students (eg: firstName,lastName,address,...etc).I want to do right click on studentDataTable (say i right click on student7) and a pop window will open which contain the student7 data in pop up window.
Thanks in advance.

I already wrote the pop up window code, not able to populate the table data into popwindow

Code for table: Component: 1 from where we are getting the student details
    ```import { Component } from '@angular/core';

````
export interface studentData {
  firstname: string;
  position: number;
  lastName: string;
  Address:string;
  contact:string;
  Age:string;

}

const ELEMENT_DATA: studentData[] = [
  {position: 1, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},
  {position: 2, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},
  {position: 3, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},
  {position: 4, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},
  {position: 5, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},
  {position: 6, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},
  {position: 7, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},
  {position: 8, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},
  {position: 9, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},
  {position: 10, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},
  {position: 11, firstname: 'Student1', lastName: 'study1', Address: 'address1',contact:'contact1',Age:'age1'},

];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'firstname','lastName','Address','contact','Age'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}```
````

HTML code for table: part of component : 1

````
```<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">   
     <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> First Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastName}} </td>
  </ng-container>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="Address">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Address </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Address}} </td>
  </ng-container>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="contact">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ContactNo </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.contact}} </td>
  </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Age">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Age </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Age}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table> ```
````

HTML Code for Pop up window: Component: 2

````
```<h1  mat-dialog-title>Student Details</h1>
<div style="float:left; border:solid;padding:8px;" > Class A
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contact No</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Class</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="float:left; border:solid;padding:8px;"> Class B  
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contact No</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Class</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>```
````

Code for open popup : Component: 2

````
    this.dialog.open(DialogDataExampleDialog, {
      data: {
        anstudentData: 'firstname'
      }
    });
  }
}```
````

Comment: Did you mean left click?

Comment: Add the code containing the pop up modal, also the code where the data is present.

Comment: right click on studentDataTable . @Ramesh . student data is coming from service

Comment: When a row is clicked you can use the index of the row which is clicked and pass the data of the clicked row to the popup modal. I can't post an answer if you don't update your question with some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click listener to a row and call a function to open the window with the relevant data in that row.

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="openStudentDialog(row)" style="cursor: pointer;"></tr>
```

And then in your component:

```
openStudentDialog(row: Student): void {
   this.matDialog.open(StudentDialogComponent, { data: { student: row } })
}
```